# Channel Form only accepting Image Uploads

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, file-manager

I've configured a channel form with the goal of receiving applications for employment. Part of this process means the user should have the ability to upload a pdf or word document to the channel.

Currently the form only accepts image uploads. If a user chooses a pdf or word doc I get an error that the file type is not accepted.

My set up is:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="job_application" logged_out_member_id="2" include_jquery="no" include_assets="no" json="yes" return="/contact-us/careers"}
<label for="applicant_resume">Upload your resum&eacute;</label>
<input id="applicant_resume" name="applicant_resume" type="file">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

**Channel Field**

Allowed file type: All

Allowed directory: Resumes

**File Upload Preferences**

- Allowed File Types: All file types

**XSS Filtering: Off**

I've tried uploading as a guest, logged in as a Client, logged in as a Super Admin and no difference. Curiously, I can log into the admin area and manage pdfs, docs, etc just fine. The error only happens with Channel Form.

Comment: Have you tried turning off xss filtering? Some pdf's seem to cause issues with this. Probably not a solution for production but it would be good to see if that is the problem. Found under Security and Privacy > Security and Sessions Preferences.

Comment: I left that out of the OP, but yes, I've disabled XSS filtering.

Comment: Have you tried variations of the channel form parameters - like include_jquery=yes include_assets=yes json=no etc..?

Comment: including jquery does nothing, including assets creates a bunch of errors with javascript, json removal breaks the form as it's submitted via ajax.

Comment: What EE & what php version you use? try to debug it - open file system\expressionengine\libraries\File_field.php and
add after line 271:
var_dump($_FILES); die(); what do you have in "type"? it was bug in some  php version with types names.

Comment: EE is 2.8.1 and php version is 5.4. Adding var_dump($_FILES); die(); does not show up when I'm in control panel or on the site, what section should I be looking in?

Comment: We all suffered from over think on this. The problem was in the directory allowed which was set incorrectly. Code is added as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="job_resume_directory" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="job_resume_hidden_file" value="{job_resume}{file_name}{/job_resume}">
```

That was the problem. The directory value should have been set to "2"

```
<input type="hidden" name="job_resume_directory" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="job_resume_hidden_file" value="{job_resume}{file_name}{/job_resume}">
```